Why (GridView.Builder) doesn't appera when i running the code?
My application runs but the grid view.builder doesn't appear
I tried to add a widget before list of row but it still doesn't
what is my fault?
how I can make it appear and solve the prolem
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("name of section"),
          Scrollbar(
            controller: _scrollController,
            thumbVisibility: true,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[ // here where I add the widget 
                  Consumer<productHome>(
                    builder: (context, value, child) {
                      return GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: 10,
                        gridDelegate:
                            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            width: 150,
                            height: 250,
                            child: Column(children: [
                              Image.asset(value.image),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            print("object");
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.add))),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      value.oldPrice,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          decoration:
                                              TextDecoration.lineThrough),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Text(value.newPrice))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [Text(value.nameOfProduct)],
                              )
                            ]),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ), 

My application runs but the grid view.builder doesn't appear
I tried to add a widget before list of row but it still doesn't
what is my fault?
how I can make it appear and solve the prolem

can you add the image of your UI that you try to achieve?

I have done my friend.

Try this solution:
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("name of section"),
    Scrollbar(
      controller: _scrollController,
      thumbVisibility: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Consumer<productHome>(
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 500, // Set the width you need for the GridView
                    height: 500, // Set a fixed height for the GridView
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      itemCount: 10,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 150,
                          height: 250,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Image.asset(value.image),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        print("object");
                                      },
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      value.oldPrice,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child: Text(value.newPrice)),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [Text(value.nameOfProduct)],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),

